# How does magic find work?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I found some gear that has the stat "increased magic find".

What is this "magic" that I can find? Gems? Potions? Some other form of loot?

I need to know what it does before I can decide if it's a stat worthy of my mighty character.

Comment: This question needs some love.

Comment: Just concluding. Does that mean that 2 lvl 63 item will have the same chance of being good no matter how high your magic find is, but you are more likely to get lvl 63 item?

Comment: @JimThio No, it means that if 2 item level 63 items drop, and you have 500% magic find for the second drop, you're 500% more likely for that drop to be a legendary (or rare etc).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Magic Find improves the chances that you will find magic/rare/set/legendary items.  It also affects the **number** of affixes that a rare item will get [[source]](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/equipment#magic-find).  It does not affect the item level of the loot that is dropped, which affixes the item gets, or the random values associated with those affixes.  It does not affect gems or potions things or other types of non-equippable items.  It does not affect the amount of items that you find (only their quality).

Here's a [recap](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41361-recap-diablo-iii-magic-find/) of how magic find works.

> Magic Find has always been one of the most popular item attributes in
>   Diablo. Magic find helps increase the probability that a higher
>   quality item will drop from monsters.
>
> - Magic Find helps increase the likelihood of Magic, Rare, Set and    Legendary items dropping.
> - The Magic Find attribute can be found on any items that are high    enough to support the affixes.
> - Magic Find is based on a percentile increase.
> - You get 20% of the MF found on your follower (source)
> - When played cooperatively items drop separately for each player. This    means each player sees their own loot and not loot that has
>     dropped    for the other people in the group. When picked up and
>     dropped on the    ground or traded the items obviously become visible
>     to the other    players as well.
> - Players will find stacking Magic Find gear more difficult than Diablo    II due to the sacrifice of other important attributes.
> - Topaz gems will add Magic Find when socketed into a Helmet.
> - There is a 300% cap on Magic Find.  Magic Find attained from Nephalem Valor is unaffected by the cap, so you can effectively get as high as 375%.

Keep in mind that your chance of getting a certain item type is multiplied by your increased magic find. For example, if you have +100% magic find, then you won't find magic items all the time.  Instead, if a legendary has a 0.1% chance to drop off of this particular monster, then it will instead have a 0.2% chance to drop (an extra 100% of it's base chance).

Comment: It affects your chance to find the items, but does it actually make the items better? If I have higher magic find, will I be more likely to find items having the higher ends of affix ranges / more affixes?

Comment: @Mag No, affix generation is separate.  It only affects the decision of what type of item will drop (Normal, Magic, Rare, or Legendary).

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uoooj/i_am_we_are_wyatt_cheng_andrew_chambers_and_jay/c4x6wpv seems to contradict you in that it *does* affect the quality of the item's attributes.

Comment: @Joey Actually, that confirms that Magic Find works exactly the same as Diablo 2.  And Blizzard has said on the Arreat Summit that Magic Find in Diablo 2 does NOT affect the generation of attributes.  Where do you see a contradiction?

Comment: Because the description there (which Jay Wilson said was correct) sounds like it *would* affect attribute generation.

Comment: @Joey, I think they just mean that magic find affects which item rarity drops.  If an iLvl 62 ring drops, more magic find increases the probability that it will be rare instead of magic, for example.  If you get a rare ring, it will always have 4-6 affixes, as opposed to the 1-3 for a magic ring.  That seems to be the only way it affects generation. I can't find a reliable source that indicates that two unidentified rare items of the same ilvl and type are any different because of the magic find a player had when they dropped. They have the same chance to be good and are essentially identical.

Comment: @Joey http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uoooj/i_am_we_are_wyatt_cheng_andrew_chambers_and_jay/c4xfij7 this comment is a few under the one you posted and seems to indicate that bwarner is correct in that you won't get better attributes, just upgraded rarity.

Comment: @bwarner I think this needs to be updated for 1.04 - particularly for party magic find determination. I think there is now a MF cap as well - not sure if that part is new.

Comment: @EBongo Thanks for the reminder.  I've updated the information so that it is no longer a direct quote (since the source is not updated), but it should now be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

### Magic Find in Patch 2.0/Reaper of Souls

I was asked to add my answer to this older question instead of making my own question regarding how much it has changed. The accepted answer is no longer valid with all the changes.

As [noted in the discussion on Magic Find gear in 2.0](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161955/what-happened-to-all-the-magic-find-gear-in-patch-2-0-reaper-of-souls), the stat has been removed from all new blue and yellow items, but continues to exist on legacy gear. It still exists on certain new legendary items, but the effect no longer is a flat bonus to all qualities of gear. Instead, [it is tiered.](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/82430-ros-faq-reaper-of-souls-frequently-asked#magicfind)

The formula for magic find is: Base chance * Bonus chance = Actual Chance

If you have 100% additional magic find in non-torment difficulty...

**COMPUTATIONS BELOW ARE EXAMPLES, AS BLIZZARD DOES NOT DISCLOSE ACTUAL DROP RATES**

**Your chance to find blue (magic) items is doubled**, meaning you are getting the full 100% bonus. So if you had a 10% chance before,    you are now at a 20% chance.  **.10 * 2 = .20**

**Your chance to find yellow (rare) items is only 30% greater**. So if you had a 5% chance before, you now have a 6.5% chance.
**.05 * 1.3 = .065**

**Your chance to find Orange (Legendary) items is only 10% greater**. So if you had a 1% chance before, you now have an 1.1% chance.
**.01 * 1.1 = .011**

You can further modify the chance for a legendary by playing on Torment I or higher difficulty. Blizzard has not disclosed the exact change in chance to find legendaries with each level of Torment, but has [confirmed that there is an additional chance with each uptick in difficulty of Torment](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12319691934), and that [certain items are only available in Torment](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10189299133). H

It should be noted that while Normal-Master difficulties do not increase the chances of a legendary at all, they also do not penalize any legendary that is found. For example, a legendary found in Normal can be just a strong as a legendary found in Torment VI stat-wise, you are simply less likely to find it.

Comment: What source do you have for these tiered rates?  That seems somewhat off.

Comment: @Frank- http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11884258481

Comment: Both of the posts being quoted have 404 links.  Perhaps that was from the beta period?  If so, a live source would be preferable.

Comment: This post is from a Blizzard moderator. http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/82430-ros-faq-reaper-of-souls-frequently-asked#magicfind

Comment: I don't think a moderator has the inside track on info from the developer.  But that's at least a live source.

Comment: The source that is now a 404 is quoted all over the place on the forums, maybe a developer said something they shouldn't have?

Comment: Could be possible.  Or it could be linked to a beta forum that's now gone.  Anything is a possibility, so finding a live source is definitely going in the right direction.  I'm just not sure how accurate it is, currently.

Answer (score 1):

I read through all of that post and I was still confused, the question is asked as your thinking but the dev reads and answers it as bwarner is thinking. The key I realized is that he said it works "exactly as it does in D2." D2 has been out for 12 years resulting in a wealth of information.

A search for MF in D2 and viola: [Diablo 2 Wiki - Magic Find](http://www.diablowiki.com/Magic_Find_%28Diablo_II%29)

The way it makes most sense to me (simplified) is like this:

1. A monster generates with all the loot it is going to drop attributes and all.
2. You kill that monster.
3. A "dice" is rolled for each item to be dropped with a percent chance of that item being the legendary version.
4. If that roll does not land a legendary item, then a "dice" is rolled with a percent chance of that item being the set version.
5. If that roll does not land a set item, then the process is continued for rare and magical.

Magic find increases the percent chance of the "dice roll." 0.1% chance to find legendary +100% MF = 0.2%

This wiki explains that the amount of bonus is less for legendary < set < rare and equal for magic. So the increase in the explanation above would be 0.177% instead of 0.2 (read it, theres a graph.)

As far as the attributes of the items, i'm guessing they have their own tiers and chance of each with a similar rolling process when the item generates with the monster.