# Does Magic Find in Diablo III work the same way as it did in the previous installment?

Tags: diablo-iii

In D2 Magic Find pushed up the quality of an item. Does it work the same way in Diablo 3? Will XX% magicfind increase my chances of a normal quality item over a inferior quality? Or does it only effect MAGIC item?

Comment: Related: [How does X% Chance of Finding Magical Items work for a party?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does increased magic find do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/what-does-increased-magic-find-do)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like in Diablo 2:

> Magic Find increases the odds for found items (from monsters or objects) to be "higher quality". Higher quality items are more likely to be magical, rare, set, or legendary, with different odds for each type of item depending on the Monster Level dropping the item and the player's Magic Find percentage.

[source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Magic_find#Magic_Find_in_Diablo_III)

Comment: hit my daily upvote limit already today. will upvote tomorrow.