# Does "x% better chance to find magical items" affect rare and legendary drop probabilities?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm wondering how much effort to put into looking for items that have "x% better chance to find magical items". The description says "magical". Does that mean *only* magical, or does it increase the chance to find rare and legendary items as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does increased magic find do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/what-does-increased-magic-find-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## YES

A magic item is any object that has magical powers inherent in it. Those are:

- Blues (Magic)
- Yellow (Rare)
- Orange (Legendary)
- Green (Tier/Set)

> **Web definitions**
>
> A magic item is any object that has magical powers inherent in it.
> These may act on their own or be the tools of the person or being
> whose hands they fall into. Magic items are commonly found in both
> folklore and modern fantasy
>
> (Magic Item) An item imbued with magic to cause a spell-like effect.

[Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20magic%20items%20diablo#hl=en&safe=off&q=magic%20items&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=hOK7T8D5IYiI9QSPpbysCg&ved=0CFgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=678d7b5b459d50f0&biw=1280&bih=879)

> **Magic Find in Diablo III**
>
> Magic Find increases the odds for found items (from monsters or
> objects) to be "higher quality". **Higher quality items are more likely
> to be magical, rare, set, or legendary**, with different odds for each
> type of item depending on the Monster Level dropping the item and the
> player's Magic Find percentage. Magic Find doesn't make items with
> higher item level to drop since monsters have a set of items they're
> capable of dropping (eg. the highest tier of items will only drop from
> monsters with Monster Level 63) nor does it increase the quantity of
> items dropped.

[Source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Magic_find#Magic_Find_in_Diablo_III)

Also [What does increased magic find do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/what-does-increased-magic-find-do)

Comment: What makes you think "magic items" entails rare, legendary and tier/set items as well? The more logical interpretation is that "magic" denotes only the magic(blue) category.

Comment: @Emiam: Magic Find also existed in earlier Diablo games, and always affects the other categories too. Or to be D3 specific, I have magic find equip and am seeing more rares (yellow) than earlier.

Comment: Answered in my edit.