# Does magic find also affect non magic items

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does increased magic find do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/what-does-increased-magic-find-do)

Does MF affect the chance of a non magic item (white) to be better. Like balanced and thick instead of broken?

Comment: There's a reason it isn't called "Chance to find better loot"...

Comment: Also overlaps with [Does magic find increase/decrease the chance of finding gems?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69672/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the stat specifically say that it increases the chance of finding magic items, as opposed to just saying "increases the chance of finding items" I would say that it only affects the chance to find magic or greater items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the magic find mechanics yet in diablo 3, but I wouldn't exclude the possibility of magic find improving the odds of getting superior quality white items.  The text indeed does say MAGIC items, but in diablo 2 it said that also. It really just improved the chances of any item being higher quality period, and that included white items.  My expectation is that % magic find will (potentially) improve a dropped item's quality similar to how diablo 2's mechanics functioned. (Focusing on the MAGIC keyword would suggest less chance of finding rare/legendary which is not the case either.)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly doubt it. Whites are only good for your first run through just to fill an empty slot.

The detail text of "magic items" would therefor disclude non-magic (white) items.

Answer (score 0):

The text for the item clearly says Increase chance of "MAGIC" find not surpirior or normal grade although i guess i can see where you are coming from with this question, maybe next time you should ask does it increase the chances of finding anything better than broken, or does it increase the chances of finding magic/rare/legendary gear.