# What does 100% Magic Find do?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does increased magic find do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/what-does-increased-magic-find-do)

What does 100% magic find actually do?
I've been above it but I still find non-magical items.

Answer (score 10):

It doubles your base chance of finding magical items. So if the *base chance* of a specific drop is 5% and you increase it by 100% it is now 10%. But **it doesn't** mean that when you have 100% magic find you find magic items all the time.

The base chance of the drop (likeliness of appearance of a magical item) is tied to the level of the monster you kill or the difficulty level and area of the container you open.

Note that the modifier full name is: `Better Chance of Finding Magical Items` (commonly abbreviated as *Magic Find* or *MF* which could seem more misleading).

If you equip your follower with magic find only 20% (one fifth) of that magic find adds to your magic find.

If you are playing with other people, each of you gets the arithmetic average magic find of the whole party. And (unlike previous Diablo titles) each of you gets and sees his own drops only.

Also see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/what-does-increased-magic-find-do).

Comment: This is the important point. It isn't 100% chance to find, it's 100% **better** chance to find.

Comment: Where do I see this separation base / total magic find? I only see Magic Find  % in the Inventory screen, when I click Details.

Comment: @MatthewScharley same question. 100% better chance of what?

Comment: @Bora, you can't see the base stat. I think in the game it is more complicated and the base chance also depends on the monster you killed - but what magic find does is it increases that said chance to find a magic item.

Comment: Edited to show what "base chance" is.