# How does Magic Find affect iLvl 61+ drops with 5NV?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does magic find work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/how-does-magic-find-work)

June 28 - Blizzard posted an update to iLvl 61+ drop rates, prompting this question of how magic find affects end-game drops.  Blizzard has stated that with 5 stacks of NV a boss will drop "at least 2 rare items" and Inferno act III & IV drop rates are as follows:

```
 | iLvl 61 |    27.1%|
 | iLvl 62 |    21.7%|
 | iLvl 63 |    16.3%|
```

Does MF gear apply directly to these rates?  For instance with 100% MF would the drop rates be as follows?

```
           |  0% MF  | 100% MF |
 | iLvl 61 |    27.1%|    54.2%|
 | iLvl 62 |    21.7%|    43.4%|
 | iLvl 63 |    16.3%|    32.6%|
```

Since the total chance for a iLvl 61+ piece of gear now exceeds 100% what gets "pushed off" the table?

Or am I headed in completely the wrong direction - does MF instead work on the "at least 2 rare items" portion of the loot table, where MF increases the chance of additional rare loot drops and doesn't affect the iLvl chance of the loot dropped?

Comment: They also call *me* robot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magic Find does not affect the chances to get a certain iLvl at all.  It only affects whether the item is Normal, Magic, Rare, or Legendary.  So magic find will increase the chance that you get more rare items, but not the level of those items.

Comment: also worth noting that MF also doesn't affect the quality of the item affixes.  For example, all ilvl 61 magic shoulders are effectively created equal, and the stats on each you receive aren't affected by your MF. Same applies for rare ilvl 61 shoulders - they are all created equal.  MF just affects the chance of that item dropping as a magic or as a rare.

Answer (score 0):

MF does not increase the chance of drop rate, but it affects the quality of the item dropped.

With increased MF, there is a higher chance that it will drop a rare than a magic.

However with the new hotfix, there is a guaranteed rare for 4 NV and 2 rares for 5 NV

Answer (score -3):

Taking your example with 100% Magic Find it would just double the chances of getting Ilevel, 61, 62 and 63 and lower, I just do not have any numbers for those chances.

Having more Magic Find does not have any impact on the stats of these items it just increases the chance to find items with those Ilevels.

So below is the current "approximate" drops in 1.0.3

Hell - Act III and Act IV:
iLvl 61: 9%,
iLvl 62: 1.9%,
iLvl 63: 0%

Inferno - Act I:

iLvl 61: 17.7%,
iLvl 62: 7.9%,
iLvl 63: 2.0%

Inferno - Act II:
iLvl 61: 18.6%
iLvl 62: 12.4%
iLvl 63: 4.1%

Inferno - Act III and Act IV
iLvl 61: 24.1%,
iLvl 62: 16.1%,
iLvl 63: 8.0%

[Source](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5238315/Patch_103_Now_Live-20_06_2012)

With 100% Magic find the chances of finding these item levels in Act 3, 4 and Wimseyshire are increased 100% like so:

Inferno - Act III and Act IV with 100% magic find
iLvl 61: 48,28%,
iLvl 62: 32,2%,
iLvl 63: 16.0%

Comment: Your source is out of date; today's patch increased the drop rates.  Also, that's not how magic find works.

Comment: This is purely wrong. Magic find will not increase the amount of ilvl 61/61/63 items that you find. The item lvl has nothing to do with magic find.

Comment: I was about to say that 1.0.3a did not change drop rates but a hot fix just came out today

Comment: My belief of how magic find is also completely wrong http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/how-does-magic-find-work

Comment: @Cresh You should edit your answer to reflect your newfound knowledge. :)