# Magic Find and item affixes?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does magic find work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/how-does-magic-find-work)

I just came across this [information](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/equipment#magic-find) and it says the Magic Find affects the number of affixes an item can have.

I always assumed it increased the chance of getting higher quality only (like Rare and Set), but apparently it also effects affixes.

Also, is it just me or is the table show in the link incorrect? Here is what it says:

```
                                            Legendary
                        6-affix rare
                        5-affix rare
                        4-affix rare
                        2-affix rare
                        1-affix rare
                        magic item
```

I have never seen a Rare item with less than 4 affixes, so I assume it was meant to go like this:

```
                                            Legendary
                                            Set
                        6-affix rare
                        5-affix rare
                        4-affix rare
                        3-affix magic
                        2-affix magic
                                            1-affix magic
```

What do you guys think? Is this something recent or was it always there?

Comment: Blizzard screwed up there; there's no way to get rares with less than 4 affixes.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you just asking whether there are 1 and 2 affix rares?  Or are you asking something about magic find?

Comment: I am asking if it has always been like this. Has magic find always increased the chance of getting higher affixed items?