# What happened to all the Magic Find gear in patch 2.0/Reaper of Souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the Vanilla version of Diablo 3, I would frequently find gear that had an effect of increasing the percentage chance to find magical items. Well I took a long break from the game, but returned after patch 2.0 changed the loot system dramatically. Upon coming back and playing for a couple weeks, I have yet to encounter a single piece of rare loot containing an additional chance to find magical items. I see plenty of effects for additional gold find and experience, but not magic find.

I did however see someone get a legendary that increased the chances of finding magic items dramatically, so I know it is not totally gone from the game, and helmets can still be socketed with a topaz to increases chances. Have they just severely lowered the chance of this effect?

Comment: See this thread on the battle.net forums, it nicely compiles the developer commentary about the issue: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11884258481

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general magic find affix has been removed from the game.  So rares and magical items will never boost magic find anymore.

There are still a few legendaries, such as the Nagel Ring, that boosts magic find.

Overall, the effect of magic find has become less useful in RoS as there is a penalty applied to it for legendary tier items for Patch 2.0+.

Comment: +1 and basically magic find is now tied to Paragon Level, amount of people in your game & difficulty you choose.

Comment: @Mkalafut- Can you expand on how it is ties to paragon level? The other stuff I'm aware of.

Comment: @Z- You say that "the general magic find affix has been removed from the game" does this mean that any pre-2.0 gear with magic find no longer has any effect?

Comment: @Tater596 no, the pre 2.0 gear retains their effect, its just no longer in the table for possible rolls of new items.  And generally considering the item difference between levle 60 and level 70, I doubt most people would be using level 60 gear for long.

Comment: Magic find still has some effect, but the effect is greatly diminished. I don't know the actual values off the top of my head, but I think it's something like 10% of your magic find will actually affect your chances to find legendaries and rares at 60.  I don't know if it still has effect at 70 though

Comment: @boiledham - I did some digging, and you're right, the effects have been changed quite a bit. I feel this deserves another Q/A specifically dealing with the effects of magic find in 2.0/RoS. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Some legendaries and sets give you magic find.. the new level 70 Cain's set for example.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that the magic find for topaz in helms no longer gives magic find but gives reduced resource cost....the gem table in inventory still says magic find but the gem it's self does not... a few items do still carry it though as mentioned above like cains set.

Answer (score -3):

The topaz adds Magic find to a Helm socket! Only way to get magic find increase now with level 70

Comment: That's not actually true (that a topaz is the "only way" to get magic find increase with level 70).  There are several legendaries that have magic find, such as the [nagelring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/nagelring).